# UnityContainer can't resolve type

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, unity-container, bootstrapper

I have a problem with resolving a type which is registered in UnityContainer. In my bootstraper I overrode ConfigureContainer method. Now this method looks like this

```
 protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {

        base.ConfigureContainer();
        RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof(IView<ShellViewModel>), typeof(Shell), false);
        RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof(CommandReaderWriter), typeof(CommandReaderWriter), true);
    }
```

Then in function CreateShell (also in bootstraper) I want to get the instance of type CommandReaderWriter so I did this

```
var raeder = Container.TryResolve<CommandReaderWriter>();
```

unfortunatelly this returns null value. I also tried

```
var anotherReader = Container.TryResolve(typeof (CommandReaderWriter));
```

but it didn't do a trick. However, interesting is the fact that

```
 var isRegistered = Container.IsTypeRegistered(typeof (CommandReaderWriter));
```

returns true.

so what is approperiate way to register singletone in UnityContainer ?

Comment: I don't know UnityBootstrapper, but I'll bet RegisterTypeIfMissing expects the first parameter to be an interface and not a class. Can you get to the IUnityContainer and just use normal Unity methods for registration?

Answer (score 0):

The two ways I use to register a singleton in Unity are:

```
_container.RegisterInstance<CommandReaderWriter>(new CommandReaderWriter);
```

and

```
_container.RegisterType<CommandReaderWriter,CommandReaderWriter>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Both these methods set the Unity LifeTimeManager to be a ContainerControlledLifeTimeManager, which is Unity-speak for a singleton.

If you want to control exactly how the object is constructed use RegisterInstance.  The second option is my preferred one because Unity then does all the dependency management for me.